# In cucumber background steps are passed for first scenario outline but failing for the second scenario outline

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber

```
Feature: search by customer
Background:
Given user selects search type as customer

Scenario Outline: search customer

 When slects customer type as customer
 Then enter the customer id as "<customer>" in search
 And clicks on search icon to search
 
  Examples:
 |customer|
 |248069  |

 Scenario Outline: Search hierarchy
 
 When slects customer type as hierarchy
 Then enter the hierarchy id as "<hierarchy>" in search 
 And clicks on search icon to search 

 Examples:
 |hierarchy  |
 |3779213 |
```

Comment: what is the specific error? Saying it fails is not enough.

Comment: Have you made any progress on this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If the second scenario results in an error when executed, I would modify the first scenario outline so that it could run both scenarios. You will need to parameterize the step definition for the first scenario outline something like this:

```
Scenario Outline: search user types

 When selects customer type as <type>
 Then enter the customer id as <id> in search
 And clicks on search icon to search
 
  Examples:
 |   type    |   id    |
 | customer  | 248069  |
 | hierarchy | 3779213 |
```

You will need to modify the step definitions that work (the ones used by the first scenario outline). My suspicion is that the step definition for the first step in the second scenario (***`slects customer type as hierarchy`***) is broken and causing your issue. Even if it is not defective, there is no good reason to have two step definition that basically do the same thing. Pass a parameter and make a decision inside the method body to make a decision based on the parameter passed if you need to execute an alternate path.

If you make these changes and the second scenario example fails, you can assume that it is due to a bad parameter being passed. In this case, the `id` parameter is one character longer in the second scenario example. It is possible this could be the problem.

Since you haven't provided a specific description of the error you are getting, it is impossible to say for certain what solution will work for you. That said, this is my best guess.